# How to make info! rneder new lines? \r\n

Tags: rust

Currently I'm logging RTSP messages like this:

```
info!(
    target: crate::LOG_RTSP,
    "S -> C: {:?}",
    String::from_utf8_lossy(buffer.as_slice())
);
```

And I get this result, which is hard to read:

```
[2021-05-02T20:37:01Z INFO  rtsp_client] C -> S: "DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.178:10554/tcp/av0_0 RTSP/1.0\r\nAccept: application/sdp\r\nAuthorization: Digest username=\"admin\", algorithm=\"MD5\", realm=\"RTSPD\", nonce=\"y0hdw5nw199f9s61s266h0z7a612zv9w\", uri=\"/tcp/av0_0\", response=\"0567e10154628e954241a22c6b369d44\"\r\nCSeq: 3\r\nUser-Agent: RRTSP Client\r\n\r\n"
```

Is there a way to get it clean, respecting the `\r\n`?

Comment: Why do you expect should happen to them? And what logger do you actually use? `info!` doesn't actually log anything, it's just a façade that dispatches to a particular logging implementation, this would definitely depend on the logging implementation.

Comment: @mcarton sorry yes your'e right. I'm using `env_logger`

Comment: Don't use the debug format? Eg. replace `{:?}` with plain `{}`.